# Java Name Program

Tags: java

> Write a method called `hasComma` that takes a name as an argument and that returns a boolean indicating whether it contains a comma. If it does, you can assume that it is in last name first format. You can use the `indexOf` `String` method to help you.
>
> Write a method called `convertName` that takes a name as an argument. It should check whether it contains a comma by calling your `hasComma` method. If it does, it should just return the string. If not, then it should assume that the name is in first name first format, and it should return a new string that contains the name converted to last name comma first format. Uses `charAt`, `length`, `substring`, and `indexOf` methods.
>
> In your main program, loop, asking the user for a name string. If the string is not blank, call `convertName` and print the results. The loop terminates when the string is blank.

However, my program doesn't return the converted name. If I type in a name like `John Smith`, the program just ends, rather than returning `Smith, John`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Type a name, then press ENTER.");
    name = reader.nextLine();
    if (name == null) {
        return;
    } else {
        convertName(name);
    }
}

public static boolean hasComma(String name) {
    return name.indexOf(',') >= 0;
}

public static String convertName(String name) {
    if (hasComma(name)) {
        return name;   
    } else {
        int index = name.indexOf(' ');
        String first = name.substring(0, index);
        String last = name.substring(index + 1);
        String convertedName = last + ", " + first;
        return convertedName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't do anything with the return value of `convertName(name)`, so Java throws it away. Perhaps you mean to print it (`System.out.println(convertName(name));`)?

Comment: You're calling convertName(), which returns the converted name. But you ignore the returned value. You should print it.: `System.out.println(convertName(name));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not printing the output of your method.

Instead of

```
convertName(name);
```

write

```
System.out.println(convertName(name));
```